# catch input on change event with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, I'm using this function:

```
jQuery(document).on('propertychange change click keyup input paste', 'input[name="wager_id_111"]', function(){
        var thisValue = jQuery(this).val();
        var amountReal = jQuery('.amount_visible');

        if ( thisValue != '' ){
            var amount_in_btc = thisValue / 1000;
            amount_in_btc = amount_in_btc.toFixed(5);
            amount_in_btc = parseFloat(amount_in_btc);
            amountReal.show(1, function(){
                amountReal.find('span').html('= ' + amount_in_btc);
            });
        } else {
            amountReal.hide();
        }
    });
```

and it works when user types amount it the input. The problem is, when input value is being changed via code, so I can't detect it was changed. Becouse there is buttons how much amount add to input (like 1, 10, 50, 100) and when users selects one of those, input value is being changed `jQuery('input[name="wager_id_111"]').val(newVal);` but as I said the function I showed below can't catch this. What the option would be to make it work?

Fiddle:

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/et3gsf9w/)

Comment: question of clarification: when you press a button (1, 10, 50, 100) you programmatically change the value of the input, and its not currently picking up that value change so you're asking if there's a way for your function to pick it up?

Comment: @indubitablee yes, this is exactly what I'm looking for. To modify my function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this line of code: `$('input[name="wager_id_111"]').trigger('change');` to your `.click()` function

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/et3gsf9w/1/

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to place the code that operates the input value into a function, and call it two times, one when the event is raised and the other one via code.

Comment: this is the worst option I could choose so I keep it in the last place, I'm looking the option how to deal with one function. And by the way - did you checked if it works? Becouse I think it will fail (I'm talking about receiving input value after changing it with .val() method)

Comment: You just send it to the function as parameter or you just can access to the value becouse you already know the id.